# Writing list into csv

Tags: python, export-to-csv, csvwriter

```
row=[]
    for row in Final_20:
        Query="select * from table where value='"+value+"'"
        c.execute(Query)
        rows.append(c.fetchall())
    with open(CSVFilename, 'w+',newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The output is inserted to one column

EX
column A column B
1 output 1 null
2 output 2 null

Comment: Where is **rows** coming from?

Comment: EX 
   column A column B 
1 output1      null 
2 output2      null

Comment: sorry first line is rows=[]

Comment: Then I think it should work now if you rename your list variable.

Comment: But I still don't get it when you mean **EX column A column B 1 output 1 null 2 output 2 null**

Comment: I didn't get it I am traveling but still, value is not  inserted to all column everything is inserted to column A

Comment: Can you include a sample of your expected result/output to your question ? Because your question is not clear.

Comment: Don't write about how there are mistakes or missing parts in your question in the comments, instead edit the question and fix the mistakes and add the missing bits.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `rows.append(c.fetchall())` you add the 2D-Array from the query as the first element of `rows`

Then your loop finds that single element and writes it.

Use `rows = c.fetchall()` instead